# data type(char) in C

Tags: c

If input is given a big number like 344565786464675345 still I get output how is this possible as char has range 256 so it should not take numbers greater than that, why char can store such big integers?

```
int main()
{
    char b[30];
    scanf("%s",b);
    printf("\n%s",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You input a string, not a char

Comment: There's a couple of well-established libraries out there that are built to deal with big numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software). Maybe you'd want to look into things like GMP, before reinventing the wheel. Because after this question (you obtain a huge integer), you'll probably find yourself asking how to subtract, add, or multiply...

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between a `char` and an array of `char`s, which is what you have.

An array is capable of storing up to 29 digits plus null terminator, but the value that you enter is *not* stored as a large integer. Instead, it is stored as a sequence of characters, where each character represents a single digit:

```
Index of b[]  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  ...
char value   '3' '4' '4' '5' '6' '5' '7' '8' '6' ...
num value     51  52  52  53  52  53  54  55  54 ...
```

All characters have numeric values in the range that can be represented by a single `char`.

Comment: If B is an integer less than 10^250 can we store this integer as char str[256] @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @AryamanTodkar Yes, we can store it like that even if we use `char`s to represent its decimal digits.

Comment: Thanks I got it @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @AryamanTodkar If we use base-256 representation, we can store 10^250 in only 104 bytes instead of 256.

Comment: @AryamanTodkar You are welcome! If you no longer need help with the problem, consider accepting an answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that your problem is solved, and also earn you a brand-new badge on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Lol he ditched you

Comment: @AwaisChishti That's OK, it happens all the time.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is array of `30` `char` and not a single `char` -

```
char b[30];   //b is an array of char
```

So `b`'s size is `30*sizeof(char)` . It means it can hold `30` characters (including `'\0'`) . Your input is stored in this character array (*sufficient for input provided*) and therefore, you can get correct output.

Comment: If B is an integer less than 10^250 can we store this integer as char str[256] @ameyCU

Comment: @AryamanTodkar Number upto `10^250` (`251` digits) can be stored in `char str[256]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char b[30];
```

b is an array and you can store up to 30 characters.

As a response to

```
scanf("%s",b);
```

You have entered 18 characters

```
344565786464675345
```

A null character `\0` has been appended to what you have entered because of the `%s` specifier which makes a total of 19 characters. Or

```
b[18]='\0' // Remember the count starts from 0
```

So you still have 11 free bytes in your array `b` as a character is 1 byte.

Mind that if you're trying store a string in the array, then the array to be null terminated, ie you need to have a `\0` at the end of a character array for the group to be considered a string.

So, technically you can have a string of up to 29 characters using `char b[30]` for it to make a valid string.

Comment: If B is an integer less than 10^250 can we store this integer as char str[256] @sjsam

Comment: You are NOT storing the integer here; you are storing a string of characters. Note that you can store an accurate representation of any integer from zero to 255 in a single character, and any integer in the range (0, 65535] in two characters, and so on.